# How to publish Pocket PC R2 in cab files and install on Window Mobile Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I have this explorer-like program in C#. I've done it finally. Now I have to be able to install this project on a phone "Windows Phone with 6.0 Framework". Can anyone answer these following questions:

1) How to publish my project to make it an installer?
2) How to run or install my project on a phone (Windows Phone with 6.0 Framework)?

Additional question:

1) What software should I use to be able to navigate my project on a phone and preview the navigation on my desktop pc? Just like remote viewing on my desktop pc from my phone?

Project information:

1) Target device -- USA Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC R2 Emulator.
2) Target Platform -- Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK
3) C# language, .Net 3.5, Visual Studio 2008

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Microsoft's documentation on it:

Deploying Windows Mobile Applications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158580.aspx

I know we are supposed to hyper link stuff, but Microsoft changes their links like I change shoes, so it is good to have the full text to search on... just in case!

Basically, you want to add another project to your solution, and this one will be your Setup project. There is a nice blog on it in [How to create a windows mobile (Smart Device).Cab installer](http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/02/how-to-create-windows-mobile-smart.html), if you can follow those steps.